# Choice of undergraduate courses impact in Computer Science PhD application

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states, undergraduate, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I’m currently a junior majoring in Computer Science with a Mathematics minor on a t20 school. Since sophomore year, I have been active in a ML research group and I’m considering in applying to grad school for a PhD lwith a focus in AI/ML. Therefore, do the courses that you take as an undergrad, matters a lot in your grad school application? And should I be focusing on taking all AI/ML related courses?

I’ve been thinking of doing a second major in Math to take more advanced courses, but they are unrelated to AI/ML.
Will it be better for me to take additional AI/ML CS courses instead of pursuing the second major? Thank you.

Comment: We deal with general Academia questions. Your question is specific to ML/AI.

Comment: Instead of another major, I would think a minor in a statistics would be more helpful overall - it would be much easier to handle while doing undergrad research and would give you the requisite rigorous mathematical background in AI/ML

Answer (score 2):

A Ph.D. admission committee wants to find reasons to believe that the applicant can do Ph.D. work. Taking hard classes and doing well in them (especially in Math) is good, but what exactly these classes offer is of secondary importance. Working on research and either getting papers or good recommendation letters is even better. In the US, there is no pressure for new Ph.D. students to immediately become research-productive, so students who need certain knowledge (e.g. Linear algebra or Optimization for ML) are expected to get it during their studies.

Based on this, I would advise you to prefer a research experience over additional course work or even a second major.